Select distinct in Drizzle Postgresql
How can I make this query return distinct resources:
 const similarGuides = await db
  .select({
    resourceId: embeddings.resourceId,
    title: resources.title,
    content: resources.content,
    type: resources.type,
    iconPath: integrations.iconPath,
    name: integrations.name,
    similarity,
  })
  .from(embeddings)
  .innerJoin(resources, eq(embeddings.resourceId, resources.id))
  .innerJoin(integrations, eq(resources.integrationId, integrations.id))
  .where(gt(similarity, 0.5))
  .orderBy(t => desc(t.similarity))
  .limit(4);

The solution should be straight forward I think but everything I try ends up in another error. I would appreciate some tips.

Yeah... Documentation on preferred method is not great in drizzle docs... A slight advantage from Prisma there.

A few things come to mind.

Found this solution over on github,

const takeUniqueOrThrow = <T extends any[]>(values: T): T[number] => {
    if (values.length !== 1) throw new Error("Found non unique or inexistent value")
    return values[0]!
  }

function foo(id: string){
    return await db.select().from(model).where(eq(model.id,id)).then(takeUniqueOrThrow)
}

which is a really great generic way to do it, using the select API.

Use findFirst, which according to the documentation, ".findFirst() will add limit 1 to the query."

function foo(id: string){
    return await db.query.model.findFirst({ where: eq(model.id, id) })
}

via the query API. Since we're on the topic of the query API, this

means you can use .findMany, and just take the first index,

function foo(id: string){
    const arr = await db.query.model.findMany({ where: eq(model.id, id) })
    if(arr !== 0) throw new Error("Found non unique or inexistent value")
    return arr[0]
}

Given the philosophy of drizzle, I believe - although haven't checked - that they are all running some form of this sql query (which is the only way to get entries)
SELECT * 
FROM table_name 
WHERE unique_column = 'value'


This also means you could just run

await db.execute(sql<model>`select * from ${model} where ${model.id} = ${id}`)

and grab the first entry, findMany, or append LIMIT 1 to the SQL query, findFirst, see the drizzle docs on sql template

Any of these methods works, and they all seem roughly equivalent in performance (pls, someone fact check me). Also, I've tested these with
$ pnpm drizzle-kit --version
drizzle-kit: v0.24.2
drizzle-orm: v0.33.0 

